# Is this punctuation correct? "Montana authors include:; John Brown, Mary Lamb..."

Tags: punctuation

I am writing a press release, and I am stumped as to what punctuation I use for listing numerous names. The following is a sample.

> Montana authors include:; John Brown, Mary Lamb, Susie Sunshine, Tom Foolery, Bud Wiser, etc.

What punctuation is correct after the word include?

Comment: You can debate the colon, but definitely dump the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

In a single sentence I would not use any type of colon, just

> Montana authors include John Brown, Mary Lamb, Susie Sunshine, Tom
>   Foolery and Bud Wiser.

Similar sentences such as

> I talked to Tom, Dick and Harry.

or

> I visited China, Japan, Singapore and Taiwan.

would be just the same. It makes no difference how many are in the list.